# A node modules file is missing a bracket - is that a global problem? Is it fixable?

Tags: angular

Everytime I click a certain function in my Angular code, the console says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

The problem is that it's not in my written code, it's in a node_modules 
file called node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.ts - I found this when i did a step-by-step debug before the error shows up.
When i did a 'find' search (ctrl+f) for brackets in this 3000-line file, it said 664 '{' and 663 '}'...  that means that it's missing a closing bracket.

I tried an online bracket spotter which colors the segments according to their bracket level - this was way too long for the program.  I also never wrote the code so I don't know what functions are what.
I tried deleting and re-downloading node_modules with npm i but it still has the same amount of brackets.
I looked in another Angular project I have to see how many brackets this file has and it didn't even have this file.

This is only some of the file, around where the problem occurs.

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @suppress {missingRequire}
 */
let passiveSupported = false;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    try {
        const options = Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
            get: function () {
                passiveSupported = true;
            }
        });
        window.addEventListener('test', options, options);
        window.removeEventListener('test', options, options);
    }
    catch (err) {
        passiveSupported = false;
    }
}
// an identifier to tell ZoneTask do not create a new invoke closure
const OPTIMIZED_ZONE_EVENT_TASK_DATA = {
    useG: true
};
const zoneSymbolEventNames$1 = {};
const globalSources = {};
const EVENT_NAME_SYMBOL_REGX = /^__zone_symbol__(\w+)(true|false)$/;
const IMMEDIATE_PROPAGATION_SYMBOL = ('__zone_symbol__propagationStopped');
function patchEventTarget(_global, apis, patchOptions) {
    const ADD_EVENT_LISTENER = (patchOptions && patchOptions.add) || ADD_EVENT_LISTENER_STR;
    const REMOVE_EVENT_LISTENER = (patchOptions && patchOptions.rm) || REMOVE_EVENT_LISTENER_STR;
    const LISTENERS_EVENT_LISTENER = (patchOptions && patchOptions.listeners) || 'eventListeners';
    const REMOVE_ALL_LISTENERS_EVENT_LISTENER = (patchOptions && patchOptions.rmAll) || 'removeAllListeners';
    const zoneSymbolAddEventListener = zoneSymbol(ADD_EVENT_LISTENER);
    const ADD_EVENT_LISTENER_SOURCE = '.' + ADD_EVENT_LISTENER + ':';
    const PREPEND_EVENT_LISTENER = 'prependListener';
    const PREPEND_EVENT_LISTENER_SOURCE = '.' + PREPEND_EVENT_LISTENER + ':';
    const invokeTask = function (task, target, event) {
        // for better performance, check isRemoved which is set
        // by removeEventListener
        if (task.isRemoved) {
            return;
        }
        const delegate = task.callback;
        if (typeof delegate === 'object' && delegate.handleEvent) {
            // create the bind version of handleEvent when invoke
            task.callback = (event) => delegate.handleEvent(event);
            task.originalDelegate = delegate;
        }
        // invoke static task.invoke
        task.invoke(task, target, [event]);
        const options = task.options;
        if (options && typeof options === 'object' && options.once) {
            // if options.once is true, after invoke once remove listener here
            // only browser need to do this, nodejs eventEmitter will cal removeListener
            // inside EventEmitter.once
            const delegate = task.originalDelegate ? task.originalDelegate : task.callback;
            target[REMOVE_EVENT_LISTENER].call(target, event.type, delegate, options);
        }
    };
    // global shared zoneAwareCallback to handle all event callback with capture = false
    const globalZoneAwareCallback = function (event) {
        // https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/911, in IE, sometimes
        // event will be undefined, so we need to use window.event
        event = event || _global.event;
        if (!event) {
            return;
        }
        // event.target is needed for Samsung TV and SourceBuffer
        // || global is needed https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/190
        const target = this || event.target || _global;
        const tasks = target[zoneSymbolEventNames$1[event.type][FALSE_STR]];
        if (tasks) {
            // invoke all tasks which attached to current target with given event.type and capture = false
            // for performance concern, if task.length === 1, just invoke
            if (tasks.length === 1) {
                invokeTask(tasks[0], target, event);
            }
            else {
                // https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/836
                // copy the tasks array before invoke, to avoid
                // the callback will remove itself or other listener
                const copyTasks = tasks.slice();
                for (let i = 0; i < copyTasks.length; i++) {
                    if (event && event[IMMEDIATE_PROPAGATION_SYMBOL] === true) {
                        break;
                    }
                    invokeTask(copyTasks[i], target, event);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I expect to be able to eliminate the error by either -

1. finding the missing bracket and putting it in.
2. repairing the file without getting into it
3. giving it an instruction not to give a warning (but not if it will impair my future code and debugging on this project).

Comment: Try to update the modules with `npm install` and update Angular, making changes to a node_module is not a good idea, especially this one

Comment: Your conclusion that a closing `}` is missing may not be correct. What if one extra opening bracket appears inside a string or a comment?

Comment: @Henry good point.  But it doesn't seem to be in my very simple file... and the error does get thrown when I'm in this particular node_modules file.  Are these the only 2 options?